# ActiveStorage directory and application migrations

Tags: capistrano, rails-activestorage

The [rails guide has no indications](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) as to setting up a server to take into account migrations.

The way things are set-up with capistrano, this means that the `storage` directory would be overwritten upon every migration - which is not going to make matters straightforward moving along.

The immediate thought is to update the `deploy.rb` file to `append :linked_dirs, 'storage'` Is this correct or is there another way to work with this?